# Help wanted: Special case of changing columns and rows MySQL

Tags: mysql

Im beginner in MySQL and want to convert this table

[image: Description]

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make it with [`CASE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/case.html) and [`UNION`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html), but only if your `Field` column has fixed values:

```
SELECT 
    T2.Field,
    T2.S,
    T2.N,
    T2.NA,
    T2.P 
FROM (SELECT
            'C1' AS Field,
            SUM(CASE WHEN T.C1='S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS S,
            SUM(CASE WHEN T.C1='N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS N,
            SUM(CASE WHEN T.C1='NA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NA,
            SUM(CASE WHEN T.C1='P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P
        FROM Table1 AS T
        UNION
        SELECT
            'C2' AS Field,
            SUM(CASE WHEN T.C2='S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS S,
            SUM(CASE WHEN T.C2='N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS N,
            SUM(CASE WHEN T.C2='NA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NA,
            SUM(CASE WHEN T.C2='P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P
        FROM Table1 AS T
        UNION
        SELECT
            'C3' AS Field,
            SUM(CASE WHEN T.C3='S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS S,
            SUM(CASE WHEN T.C3='N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS N,
            SUM(CASE WHEN T.C3='NA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NA,
            SUM(CASE WHEN T.C3='P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P
        FROM Table1 AS T
        UNION
        SELECT
            'Cn' AS Field,
            SUM(CASE WHEN T.Cn='S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS S,
            SUM(CASE WHEN T.Cn='N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS N,
            SUM(CASE WHEN T.Cn='NA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NA,
            SUM(CASE WHEN T.Cn='P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P
        FROM Table1 AS T) AS T2;
```

**Test:**

```
mysql> SELECT  T2.Field,         T2.S,         T2.N,         T2.NA,         T2.P      FROM (SELECT 'C1' AS Field, SUM(CASE WHEN T.C1='S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS S, SUM(CASE WHEN T.C1='N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS N, SUM(CASE WHEN T.C1='NA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NA, SUM(CASE WHEN T.C1='P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P FROM Table1 AS T UNION SELECT 'C2' AS Field, SUM(CASE WHEN T.C2='S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS S, SUM(CASE WHEN T.C2='N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS N, SUM(CASE WHEN T.C2='NA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NA, SUM(CASE WHEN T.C2='P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P FROM Table1 AS T UNION SELECT 'C3' AS Field, SUM(CASE WHEN T.C3='S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS S, SUM(CASE WHEN T.C3='N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS N, SUM(CASE WHEN T.C3='NA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NA, SUM(CASE WHEN T.C3='P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P FROM Table1 AS T UNION SELECT 'Cn' AS Field, SUM(CASE WHEN T.Cn='S' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS S, SUM(CASE WHEN T.Cn='N' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS N, SUM(CASE WHEN T.Cn='NA' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NA, SUM(CASE WHEN T.Cn='P' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS P FROM Table1 AS T) AS T2;
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| Field | S    | N    | NA   | P    |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
| C1    |    1 |    1 |    1 |    1 |
| C2    |    2 |    1 |    0 |    1 |
| C3    |    3 |    1 |    0 |    0 |
| Cn    |    0 |    3 |    1 |    0 |
+-------+------+------+------+------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Thank you. It works! now I´ll will have to deal with performance, because n =335

Comment: @AlejandroDeLeon you should instead deal with a redesign to do it properly so you do not have to do this.